# How can I listen any of the document event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using the `Elementor` plugin in WordPress, and I'd like to know what events are triggered by this plugin while the preview page is loading.

So, I don't know how *( and if that's possible of course )* can listen to any triggered events and log them in the console.

At the moment I have tried several solutions I found on the internet, including the `monitorEvents(document.body)`, but I took no valuable information as the common solutions on the internet are related to common events, like mouse events, keyboard events, elements load events, etc.

For example, from the `Elementor` plugin documentation I know that there is an event called `elementor:init`, but using all those methods available currently on the internet, I cannot catch that kind of event.

Keep in mind, I don't mind if it's possible to see the data emitted for the given event. I am happy with only see the event name.

Also, keep in mind that I need this information just for debugging purposes. So, if you have any alternative method that can let me access the events, will be very welcome. For example, let's say, if there's a kind of events registry in the window, and I can access it, then this could be also very helpfull.

So is there any way to check the triggered events using JavaScript?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [JS Hooks](https://github.com/pojome/elementor/blob/master/docs/content/hooks/js-hooks.md) ? Maybe there is something useful. The **init** hook looks promising.

Comment: @DavidDomain, yes, I have look on those hooks, but unfortunately seems like they don't work. From a [ticket](https://github.com/pojome/elementor/issues/2510), I open a few weeks ago, they told me that I have to run my scripts after the `elementor:init`. Unfortunately in my case, the `elementor:init` in the preview editor doesn't work at all.